# How to get ribbon back in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, ribbon

I emailed myself a copy of an excel/vba project that I had.  The project was developed in Excel 2013.  When I opened it, the ribbon tab was gone.  I have tried searching for several solutions but haven't found any matching this exact issue.  I don't have a tools tab or anything accessible to me.  When I click the excel icon top left it says "restore, minimize, close".  I have a formula bar, but that's about it.

Are there any VBA snippets I could use at workbook open that might solve this issue?

Comment: Try this: 'Start / Control Panel / Programs / Repair' and repair Excel (Credit from:http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/700157-excel2013-entire-toolbar-ribbon-missing.html)

Answer (score 0):

I just realized what I did.

I have a userform that maximizes to full screen on workbook open.  I minimized excel as to hide it from view.

```
Application.Parent.Visible = False
```

To correct this issue, I simply wrote a backdoor for myself upon userform close to re-enable the userform.

```
Application.Parent.Visible = True
```

Problem solved.  All tools and the ribbon have been restored.